# How to manually execute WYMeditor function w/o errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wymeditor, wysiwym

For debug, watch [`jquery.wymeditor.js`](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/blob/master/dist/wymeditor/jquery.wymeditor.js).

I need to execute commands like "Strong", "Indent", etc. from my custom toolbar (to be precise, ribbon) via JavaScript and without errors. 80% are done, I can execute commands, but have a strange error.

So, what I do, when document is ready (with contained textarea "#doc"):

```
myDoc = $("#doc").wymeditor()[0];
myDoc_wym = $.getWymeditorByTextarea(myDoc);

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(myDoc_wym._iframe.contentWindow); // contentWindow returns proper Window object of editor IFrame
    $(myDoc_wym._doc).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 112) {
            console.log(myDoc_wym); // must return extended jQuery editor object
            myDoc_wym.__proto__._exec("Strong"); // BREAKPOINT
            console.log("It might be done!"); // no luck today
            return false;
        }
    });
}, 1000); // to be sure, that myDoc_wym._doc exists, I just enforced timeout
```

1. WYMeditor on half way to be fully prepared.
2. Get its extended `editor` object with `getWymeditorByTextarea`.
3. Wait a second.
4. Log `Window` object of editor's IFrame.
5. When we press `F1`:

   1. Log `myDoc_wym`.
   2. `myDoc_wym.__proto__._exec("Strong");` - execute prototyped function `_exec` with command `"Strong"`...

Here goes a crash of `keydown`. What I get in Chromium (above last released NW.JS) console:

[image: Whole log]

Error is caused in prototyped function `hasSelection`. So, it's saying that `_iframe` is `undefined` in that code:

```
WYMeditor.editor.prototype.hasSelection = function () {
    var wym = this;

    if (
        // `isSelectionValid` is undocumented in current Rangy (`1.2.2`).
        // It seems to be required because the `rangeCount` in `IE <= 8` seems
        // to be misleading.
        rangy.isSelectionValid(wym._iframe.contentWindow) !== true
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    if (wym.selection().rangeCount === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

After this tried to enable my own call for this function by pasting in console input similar code, but with debug needs (`console.log(wym);`):

```
WYMeditor.editor.prototype.hasSelection = function () {
    var wym = this;
    console.log(wym);
    //console.log(wym._iframe);
    //console.log(wym._iframe.contentWindow);
    if (rangy.isSelectionValid(wym._iframe.contentWindow) !== true) return false;
    if (wym.selection().rangeCount === 0) return false;
    return true;
};
```

Pressing `F1`:
[image: Playing with custom function]

1. First object is what I get **before** executing WYMeditor command.
2. Second has no `_iframe`, so it's returning undefined.
3. Accordingly, cannot read from undefined.
4. It seems like `hasSelection` is called twice (for example, `selectedContainer`, that calls `hasSelection`, may be called 3 times by `_exec`). At this time we see `_iframe`, but it isn't longer needed.

It turns out that:

1. at *first time* `hasSelection` called, **`wym` returned as prototyped object**, but...
2. at *second time* `wym` returned as full "editor object" with needed properties (such as `_iframe`).

[image: Weird object]

Something weird going up there and I don't know what. When pressing on default toolbar buttons all works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use only public API

Here (a bit too tucked away for my taste) are the docs for [WYMeditor's public API](http://wymeditor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_plugins/api.html).

Interact with WYMeditor only through what's documented there, if possible.

If you use private methods/properties, we couldn't reasonably support that use.

If a property/method starts with an underscore, it is private.

## What you're trying to do

Please rewrite your implementation using the public API.

You'll find [combokeys](http://wymeditor.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0.5/writing_plugins/api.html#keyboard-combokeys) and [`exec`](http://wymeditor.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0.5/writing_plugins/api.html#exec-cmd) (not `_exec`) useful for what it seems to me you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a cheating from my side, when I was using __proto__. I have resorted to it, cause `exec` wasn't working with `"Strong"`, so now I tried `"Bold"` and it works! Thanks.